# Median of large amount of numbers for each sets of given size

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

The question is :

> find median of a large data(n numbers) in fixed size (k) of numbers

What i thought is :
maintain 2 heaps , maximum heap for numbers less than current median and minimum heap for numbers greater than current median .
The main concept is to **FIND** the 1st element of previous set in one of the heap (depending on it is < or > current median), and replace it with the new element we encounter .
Now modify such as to make |size(heap1) - size(heap2)| = 1 or 0 because median is avg. of top element if size1 != size2 else the top element of the heap with size > size of other .

The problem i am facing is the time complexity increases because **finding** the element takes O(n) time so total `O(n*k)`, so i am not able to achieve the desired complexity `O(n*logk)` (as was required in source of the question).

How should it be reduced , without using extra space ?

edit : input : 1 4 3 5 6 2  , k=4
median :
from 1 4 3 5 = (4+3)/2
from 4 3 5 6 = (4+5)/2
from 3 5 6 2= (3+5)/2

Comment: You mean you have *n* integers, but only *k* distinct ones?

Comment: @larsmans i mean i have total n integers and find median of all continuous sets of size k .

Comment: I still don't undertand. Please describe the problem properly. And give an example.

Comment: Right, so you want the median of each length-*k* window (subarray, contiguous subsequence) of an array?

Comment: yes , you are right , maybe i put it in confusing words.

Comment: It's still confusing. Why is the time complexity O(n²)? Is k allowed to vary up to n?

Comment: @larsmans sorry it should be n*k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using an [order-statistic tree](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/OrderStatisticsTree), which is a BST with some additional information that allows finding medians, quantiles and other order statistics in O(log *n*) time in a tree with *n* elements.

First, construct an OST with the first *k* elements. Then, in a loop:

1. Find and report the median value.
2. Remove the first element that was inserted into the tree (you can find out which element this was in the array).
3. Insert the next element from the array.

Each of these steps takes O(log *k*) if the tree is self-balancing, because we maintain the invariant that the tree never grows beyond size *k*, which also gives O(*k*) auxiliary space. The preprocessing takes O(*k* log *k*) time while the loop repeats *n* + 1 - *k* times for a total time of O(*n* log *k*).

Comment: that is great link . Let me know if i understood it incorrectly :  
for each window , delete the 1st element of window and insert new element , now call `FindByRank(k/2) , if k=even` else `mean of FindByRank(k/2) and FindByRank(k/2 +1) , if k= odd` .  


one doubt : 
don't we still have to update all ranks after inserting new element ? making it O(k) per step?

Comment: @anon: that's it. The great thing about order-statistic trees (see also Cormen's *Introduction to Algorithms*, chapter 16) is that the rank update takes logarithmic time. It's folded into the insertion.

Comment: well , i will see cormen , thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a balanced tree implementation that gives you efficient access to the central element you should probably use it. You could also do this with heaps much as you suggest, as long as you keep an extra array of length k which tells you where each element in the window lives in its heap, and which heap it is in. You will have to modify the code that maintains the heap to update this array when it moves things around, but heap code is a lot easier to write and a lot smaller than balanced tree code. Then you don't need to search through all the heap to remove the item which has just gone off the edge of the window and the cost is down to n log k.

Comment: by `array` you mean to hash the `address of x with x` ? and if we swap two values in heap , change accordingly in hash also .

Comment: I don't think you need a hash - if the window length is k you could use an array of length k and set array[i % k] to the position of element i in the heap, perhaps making this -ve if it is in the min heap and +ve if it is in the max heap. Then yes, when you swap items i and j in the heap swap the values in array[i % k] and array[j % k].

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems like the one which you have in efficient implementation in dijkstra shortest path where we need to delete(update in case of dijkstra) an element which is not at top of heap.But you can use the same work around to this problem but with extra space complexity. Firstly you cannot use inbuilt heap library, create your own heap data structure but maintain pointers to each element in the heap so while adding or removing element update the pointers to each element. So after calculating median of first k elements delete the first element directly from heap (min or max) according to whether it is greater or less than median using pointers and then use `heapify` at that position. Then sizes of heaps change and then you can get new median using same logic as you are using for adjusting the heap sizes and calculating median.

`Heapify` takes `O(logk)` hence your total cost will be `O(n*logk)` but will need `O(n)` more space for pointers.

Comment: yes this is what i thought initially but it will not work for duplicate elements .

Comment: say you have changed address at which X lies (during swapping) and make a change in array[X] also , but we may have more than 1 X , in input . if you try to use some tree or hash-map or multiset , still you may be wanting to update X but may update X' .

Comment: @anon you dont need a hash set or anything else just an array int pointer[n] where position of ith element in original array is in pointer[i] position of heap so duplicate elements will not cause any problem in this case.

Comment: @anon donot insert values into heap insert indices of element in original array using arr[i] for comparisons.