# Finding Median in Large Integer File of Integers

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I was asked in an interview the following. I didn't get it but trying to solve it at home. I believe we have to use the Median of Median algorithm...

> Q: Finding Median in Large Integer File of Integers
>
> Find the median from a large file of integers. You can not access the
>   numbers by index, can only access it sequentially. And the numbers
>   cannot fit in memory.

I found a solution online (rewrote in Python) but there are a few things I do not understand.. I kind of get the algorithm but not 100% sure.

a) Why do we check `left >= right`?

b) When `count < k`, we call `self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,k,max(result+1,guess),right)`. Why do we call `max(result+1, guess)` as `left`?

c) when `count > k`, why do we use `result` as `right`?

```
class Solution:

def findMedianInLargeFile(self, numbers,k,left,right):

    if left >= right:
        return left

    result = left
    guess = (left + right ) // 2
    count = 0

    # count the number that is less than guess

    for i in numbers:
        if i <= guess:
            count+=1
            result = max(result,i)

    if count == k:
        return result
    elif count < k: # if the number of items < guess is < K
        return self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,k,max(result+1,guess),right)
    else: 
        return self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,k,left,result)



def findMedian(self, numbers):
    length = len(numbers)

    if length % 2 == 1: # odd
        return self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,length//2 + 1,-999999999,999999999)
    else:
        return (self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,length//2,-999999999,999999999) + self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,length//2 +1 ,-999999999,999999999)) / 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) by median value

Compare with example code

```
function binary_search(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n − 1
    while L <= R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T:
            L := m + 1
        else if A[m] > T:
            R := m - 1
        else:
            return m
    return unsuccessful
```

- `if left >= right:` stops iterations when borders 
  collide
- when `count < k`, we call `self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,k,max(result+1,guess),right)` because our guess was too small, and median value is bigger than quessed value.
- similar but reversed situation for `else` case

Comment: Ahhh that's right. Thank you @mbo. Why is there the use of "result = max(result,i)" Also, why aren't we subtracting 1 in "return self.findMedianInLargeFile(numbers,k,left,result)"

Comment: We don't subtract 1 because right border is excluded (similar as Python does). Max condition - to treat cases when number < left

Answer (score 0):

You could perform merge sort with -- O(nlogn) -- on the external memory as it is implemented to operate on data sequentially.

An interesting solution could be through an order-statistic tree, with the implementation available here: [Median of large amount of numbers for each sets of given size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073127/median-of-large-amount-of-numbers-for-each-sets-of-given-size)

however, if you have any questions -- let me know!